# Beginning ruby example produces no output

Tags: ruby

I am learning from the book beginning ruby on rails by Steve Holzner, and am trying out some of the code in the book:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
until($_ != "q")
  puts "Running"
  print "Enter q to quit: "
  gets
  chomp
end
```

When I run the Program, nothing happens!

Comment: how are you running the program?  What environment (OS, ruby version)?

Comment: What do you suppose `$_` contains when you start this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_` is `nil` when the process starts.  So, the `until` condition is immediately satisfied, and doesn't even run the loop once.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to repeat until the letter entered *is* `q`, your first line should be;

```
until($_ == "q")
```

Right now, `$_` is not set to `q` when getting there the first time, so it will immediately exit the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be `until($_ == "q")`

The way you have it is suggesting that it runs until anything except "q" is inputed. So it will quit when anything is typed and if q is typed then it will continue.

Answer (score 2):

`$_` is going to return `nil` when you run this program. Because `nil` is != to `q`, the program doesn't even run at all. It will exit with `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed your code, brah

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
foo = ''
while foo != 'q'
  puts "Running"
  print "Enter q to quit: "
  foo = gets 
  foo.chomp!
end
```